Querying a pdf body in ElasticSearch as nested fields along with other flattened data
I am using python libraries for elasticsearch, but help in raw elasticsearch query/mapping will be helpful too.
For every project, there can be N number of files and some extra data. I want to index and search all the information fields for the project and also index the files for them. I have the following mapping:
# documents.py

class ProjectDocument(Document):
    project_name = fields.TextField(analyzer=text_analyzer)
    files = fields.NestedField(properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'content': fields.NestedField(
            properties={
                'page': fields.IntegerField(),
                'body': fields.TextField(analyzer=doc_analyzer)
            }
        )
    })
    
    file_names = fields.TextField(analyzer=text_analyzer)
    mdt = fields.TextField(analyzer=text_analyzer)

What I want to achieve is: for a search query, perform a multi_match on the following fields project_name, file_names, mdt; and perform a match_phrase on files.content.body. The resultant score/hit should be a mix of both queries with appropriate highlights.
The way I see the files hits returning is that it which page number it found the matched phrase in, a highlight of the phrase fragment, and a count of the number of matches in the file. Something like (only for demonstration purposes of the kind of context the results would be in):
Page 1: ..... hello world ...
Page 2: ... the world is saying hello ... the hellos of the world ... 
+ 234 more matches for 'hello world' in the file

I am relativly new to ElasticSearch and was able to achieve basic individual searching but am struggling when it comes to nested fields where a project can have multiple pdfs and each pdf can have multiple pages which need to be indexed and queried. Will appreciate any help in the direction of solving this.

don't use nested field but simply denormalize the index https://medium.com/@jeremy.gachet/denormalization-for-elasticsearch-index-984ce7cfa50a
